# How to merge hot fix on branch to master

Tags: git

If I start with a structure like follows on my remote:

```
A-B-C-D-F-G  master
   \
    E-H-I  branch
```

And I clone branch and make change 'J' (& commit and push to remote branch) how can I merge 'J' to master without bringing down 'H' and 'I'? Can it be done just by pushing change 'J' or do I need to switch to a local repo tracking master and merge the local 'J' change and push that to master?

```
A-B-C-D-F-G-J  master
   \       
    E-H-I-J  branch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a history that reflects reality and so save yourself potential trouble downstream,

```
git checkout -b Jbranch B
git cherry-pick J
git checkout -B branch I
git merge Jbranch
git checkout -B master G
git merge Jbranch
git branch -d Jbranch
```

Producing

```
A..B..C..D..F..G..J''  master
   |             /
   |\........J'.+
   |             \ 
    \....E..H..I..J    branch
```

The 'J' commit's tree in the old and new 'branch' tip will be identical, just with the explicit history this time.

Comment: Any idea why cherry-pick(ing) J directly from branch to master would cause me later merge troubles. Surely the merge is capable of seeing C-D-F-G-J and H-I-J have J in common and only merge H & I. Most other version control systems do this, whats different with Git?

Comment: It's a pure safety play, just like any vcs git can identify the cherry-pick because the two commits apply patches that look the same, but any system that works on detecting similarities like this can be fooled.

Answer (score 1):

You can [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the change J. Cherry-picking only copies a particular commit to a branch.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick J
```

Note that commit J will now be duplicated (it'll exist on each branch).